# Can a function be created in MATLAB that returns nothing?

Tags: matlab, function

I want to write a function that does some image processing and writes the processed images to files. I don't want it to return anything. I can always return a dummy variable which can be ignored, but I'd like to keep my code clean. How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes.

```
function [] = my_awesome_function(image,filename,other_inputs)
    % Do awesome things.
end
```

will return nothing. An even simpler version:

```
function my_awesome_function(image,filename,other_inputs)
    % Do awesome things.
end
```

is equivalent.